# Data does not change using ternary operator on Linechart

Tags: reactjs, linechart

I want to render different data on my Line Chart Widget component depending on the user input. So I created a select tag:

```
<select id="lang" onChange={this.handleLineChart} value={this.state.value}>
          <option value="indiaData">All India</option>
          <option value="stateData">States</option>
</select>
```

constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'indiadata'
    }
   this.handleLineChart = this.handleLineChart.bind(this);
}
```

Onchange Event

```
    handleLineChart(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
```

My component

```
    {
        this.state.value === "indiaData" ? 
          <LineChartWidget data={indiaData} /> :
          <LineChartWidget data={stateData} />
    }
```

Both my data "indiaData" and "stateData" are arrays of objects and I am fetching 'em through API. 
By default, it works perfectly while rendering indiaData but when I change the input to States, it does not show any data on the line chart, though I can log it in my console (on change of input). There are no issues with the data.

Also, if I reverse my default state value to

```
     this.state = {
        value: 'statedata'
     }
```

and my component to exactly opposite

```
    {
        this.state.value === "stateData" ? 
          <LineChartWidget data={stateData} /> :
          <LineChartWidget data={indiaData} />
    }
```

Then, it will render stateData and not indiaData on changing the input.

There is one more scenario, so when my component looks something like this

```
    {
        this.state.value === "stateData" ? 
          <LineChartWidget data={stateData} /> :
          <div>Test</div>
    }
```

It works perfectly with the div but not with the second Linechart.

Shortly, my issue here is that it only renders the first condition and not the second one, keeping in mind that there is no issue with the data.

Comment: set breakpoint on this line `this.state.value === "indiaData" ? `, is it called after changing of input? what is value of `this.state.value`?

Comment: I can see state changing on user input. I can see data coming through. But it does not render the data on Line chart. Also edited the question.

Comment: Post the relevant code and how it all relates to each other. Where is the `<select>` rendered? Where is the `this.state.value === ` code? Post it all in cohesive block that shows how it fits together.

Answer (score 0):

Inside select tag, bind the scope using .bind(this)

```
<select id="lang" onChange={this.handleLineChart.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}>
      <option value="indiaData">All India</option>
      <option value="stateData">States</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it in the question itself, but I have already binded my function in my constructor. I can see it working after logging this.state.value in my console.

Comment: Although, at first look, it seems like new data passed is same as previous data, but try to re-render LineChartWidget by setting state in `componentWillReceiveProps()` of LineChartWidget component

Answer (score 0):

Your function `handleLineChart()` doesn't have access to `this`. You can bind it correctly like so:

```
handleLineChart = (event) => {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Already binded. Sorry did not mention in the question itself.

Comment: @VinaySingh well can you include your full code please?

Comment: @VinaySingh it's not bound anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: Updated the question. My apologies.